# how to combine two sql statements into a function

Tags: function, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to combine the following two sql statements in my application code into a function in postgresql, but I'm having some trouble. 
Here are the two sql queries I'd like to combine:

```
UPDATE userrange f 
SET UsedYesNo = true, user_id=user_id, updateddatetime=now()
WHERE f.uservalue IN(
    SELECT a.uservalue FROM userrange a WHERE UsedYesNo=false Order By id ASC Limit 1)
    RETURNING a.uservalue;
```

The results from the above statement are used in this query:

```
   INSERT INTO widget 
   VALUES(DEFAULT, uservalue, 'test','123456778',1,"testservername", now(), Null)
```

So far, I've built function that just does the first update statement, like so:

```
CREATE or REPlACE FUNCTION create_widget(IN user_id integer, IN password character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying)
  RETURNS TABLE(uservalue integer) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

    RETURN QUERY
UPDATE userrange f SET UsedYesNo = true, user_id=user_id, updateddatetime=now()
    WHERE f.uservalue IN(
    SELECT a.uservalue FROM userrange a WHERE UsedYesNo=false Order By id ASC Limit 1)
    RETURNING a.uservalue;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

It compiles but when I execute it, it fails with the error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "a" LINE 4:  RETURNING a.uservalue
```

I'm just googling this error to see how I can fix it... but could I just create a variable 
called uservalue in a DECLARE section and use it in the secondary query?  Or can i combine the sql into one

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can forego the function and you have PostgreSQL 9.2+, you can do the update and insert in a single query. It should be straightforward to port this to a function if necessary.

```
WITH f AS (
    UPDATE userrange f
    SET UsedYesNo = true, user_id=user_id, updateddatetime=now()
    WHERE UsedYesNo IS FALSE
    RETURNING f.uservalue)
INSERT INTO widget (<column list>)
SELECT f.uservalue, 'test','123456778',1,"testservername", now(), NULL
FROM f;
```

-- [edit: added function]
-- Note: the following function is untested

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_widget(IN p_user_id INTEGER, IN p_password VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL::VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE(uservalue integer) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        WITH f AS (
            UPDATE userrange f
            SET UsedYesNo = true,
                user_id = p_user_id,
                updateddatetime = now()
            WHERE UsedYesNo IS FALSE
            RETURNING f.uservalue)
        INSERT INTO widget (<column_list>)
        /*  Omit the DEFAULT, by not including it in the column list above,
        *   the DEFAULT already defined on the column will be used.
        */
        SELECT f.uservalue, 'test','123456778',1,"testservername", now(), NULL
        FROM f;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: The key word `DEFAULT` can be used in a `VALUES` expression, but not in a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. I've updated my response to reflect that change.